# Корректная сортировка в tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть колонка, в которой значения 2 000 Р, 100 Р, 1 500 Р и т.п.

При сортировке идут криво. Понятно, что дело в string типе.
Не могу найти на сайте разработчика внятную инфу как сортировать такие строки. Может знает кто ?

Comment: А в чем именно заключается проблема с сортировкой? Вроде бы все просто: в компараторе парсишь числа (`+(x.replace(/\D/g, ''))`), и возвращаешь их разность. Или этот самый tablesorter не позволяет свой компаратор использовать?

Comment: @yar85 плагин это умеет, судя по англ. ответам. Вот только не пойму как включить эту опцию (виджет)

Comment: А, понятно... но этого я тоже не знаю, сорри :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не могу найти на сайте разработчика внятную инфу как сортировать такие строки.

Rly? Там в документации буквально сразу видно раздел "How to" и ссылку [Custom sort script](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-custom-sort.html) в нем.

Собственный компаратор указывается в объектном параметре `textSorter` конфига - где именем свойства является числовой индекс столбца таблицы, а значением функция:

```js
generateTable();
const parseNumber = str => +(str.replace(/\D/g, ''));

$('table').tablesorter({
  textSorter: {
    1: (a, b) => parseNumber(a) - parseNumber(b),
  },
});





// все что ниже - неинтересная фигня, нужная только для демки.
function generateTable() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', `<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Foo</th><th>Bar</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>`);
  const tBody = $('tbody').get(0);
  const rndNum = (max, min = 0) => Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
  const rndStr = length => {
    const dict = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
          dictSize = dict.length;
    return Array.from({ length }, () => dict.charAt(rndNum(dictSize))).join('');
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    const tr = tBody.insertRow();
    tr.insertCell().textContent = `${rndStr(8)} ${rndStr(5)}`;
    tr.insertCell().textContent = rndNum(1e5, 1e3).toLocaleString('ru-RU', {
      style: 'currency',
      maximumFractionDigits: 0,
      currency: 'RUB',
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tablesorter/dist/css/theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tablesorter"></script>
```

Comment: И без кастомного компаратора тоже вполне нормально сортирует...

Comment: хм..помечу как ответ, однако не помогает, если значения генерируются на стороне сервера..хз почему, но сортирует через опу.. (скрин) https://ibb.co/TPNf2Bn

Comment: @sousage1212, для того в вопрос и добавляют [repro], чтобы проблему воспроизводить - а то хз что там генерирует используемый тобой сервер (к тому же, если он генерит хитрые символы которые не преобразуется в числа, сортирующим jQuery-плагином эту генерацию не исправить в любом случае: тогда либо фиксить серверный код, либо перекодировать данные при их получении). С буквой "Р" из вопроса пример тоже работает исправно, при желании можешь проверить это через `replace`... так что либо символы цифр в серверном ответе "какие-то не такие", либо что-то не так делаешь :)

Comment: обычный rand + number_format на стороне сервера. Из за number_format к слову говоря и не хочет. Если убрать пробел - сортируется идеально..бредятина такая. Кто б мог подумать..

Comment: @sousage1212, посмотри в код внимательнее: функция `parseNumber` выкидывает из входной строки все нечисловые символы перед типкастом, поэтому пробелы мешать никак не могут (компаратор сравнивает числа, тип `number`. В числах пробелов нет, и быть не может).

Comment: хрен его знает.. (скрин) https://ibb.co/njv9yKS. Это если убрать разделение групп в number_format. Если поставить - будет криво сортировать. Даже с parseNumber функцией

Comment: @sousage1212, еще раз: посмотри внимательнее в код, **пробелы удаляются из строки** перед ее приведением к числовому типу, поэтому влиять они не могут чисто технически. Если у тебя пробелы влияют на результат - значит, сделал что-то иначе, чем показано в коде примера. Других вариантов быть не может. Разве пример криво сортирует? Если не криво, то откуда тогда взялась уверенность что дело именно в пробелах, а не в плохо скопированном коде? Он ведь не может работать по-разному при одинаковых входных данных.

Comment: @sousage1212, просто задай новый вопрос об отладке кода, добавив в него [repro] (запускаемым сниппетом) с неправильной сортировкой - и посмотрим что там происходит, в чем там проблема.